# Kendo Inline editing - dropdown value returns to pre-select

Tags: kendo-ui, inline-editing

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline

As seen in the demo from the link above, I have a similar grid in my project. When i press the edit button button the value for the dropdown returns to --Please Select-- unlike in the demo above. I would appreciate if anyone could what could be the root cause.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Can't help much without seeing the code. Did you read this? https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn